# How to get Java to return an exact value to a calculation as opposed to a decimal form?

Tags: java, math

How would I return an exact value to a calculation, i. e.: `4 * sqrt(3)` as opposed to the decimal form?

EDIT: Sorry, I thought this was a basic question. Here is my code:

```
package physics;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Physics {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("do you want to \n [1] find the magnitude from components \n [2] find the components from magnitude and angle \n [3] Dot product from magnitude" + 
            "\n [4] Gravitational problems" );
    int key = in.nextInt();
    switch(key){
        case 1:
            compsToMag();
            break;
        case 2:
            magToComps();
            break;

        case 3:
            dotProductWithMags();
            break;
        case 4:
            gravity();
            break;
    } 
}

public static double compsToMag(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter x, [Enter], then y comp");
    double x = input.nextDouble();
    double y = input.nextDouble();

    double mag = Math.sqrt((x*x) + (y*y));

    System.out.print("Magnitude = " + mag);
    return mag;

}

public static void magToComps(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter magnitude to find components");
    int magnitude = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter angle in degrees");
    double angle = input.nextDouble();

    double x = magnitude * (Math.cos(angle));
    double y = magnitude * (Math.sin(angle));

    System.out.println("X = " + x + " \n Y = " + y);
}

public static double dotProductWithMags(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter magnitude of vector 1");
    int mag1 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter magnitude of vector 2");
    int mag2 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter angle");
    double angle = input.nextDouble();

    double result = mag1 * mag2 * Math.cos(angle);

    System.out.print("dot product result = " + result);
    return result;
}

public static void gravity(){
           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   double G = 6.674 * Math.pow(10, (-11));


   System.out.println("Mass 1 'base' [base * 10^(exponent)]:");
   double mass1 = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Mass 1 'exponent' [base * 10^(exponent)]:");
    double mass1Exp = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Mass 2 'base':");
    double mass2 = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Mass 2 'exponent':");
    double mass2Exp = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("radius/distance apart:");
    double rad = input.nextDouble();

    double force = (G * (mass1 * Math.pow(10, mass1Exp)) * (mass2 * Math.pow(10, mass2Exp))) / (Math.pow(rad, 2));

    double accelerationMass1 = force/mass1;
    double accelerationMass2 = force/mass2;

    System.out.println("Force of gravity = " + force);
    System.out.println("Acceleration of mass1 = " + accelerationMass1);
    System.out.println("Acceleration of mass2 = " + accelerationMass2);
}
```

}

I just want to be able to return an exact value with a square root sign as opposed to a decimal

Comment: Show us how you are performing your calculation? Which classes are involved, what methods are called and what are their return types?

Comment: The square root of three is not a rational number. It can not be represented by a finite or repeating decimal with digits after the decimal point and it can not be represented as the ratio of two numbers. What is it that you want? Four times it is also irrational.

Comment: Very unclear question. Consider improving.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the exact value. You should consider using a **math library** that provides **symbolic calculations**.

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574949/is-there-something-like-sympy-for-java).